# docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I try to use docxtpl library. [docxtpl](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) Use example from documentation:

```
    from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

    doc = DocxTemplate("my_word_template.docx")
```

But there is an error `Package not found at '%s'" % pkg_file`. If I do this

```
import os.path

if os.path.isfile('my_word_template.docx'):
    print ("File exist")
```

It is print `File exist`. File in the same directory as script. Also I tried to use absolute path to file, but that didn't help. In a source I found a place which calls this exception [link](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/opc/phys_pkg.py#L24). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It probably indicates that the file is not a .docx file. Could you, please, check this file using function `is_zipfile` from module `zipfile`?

Comment: `is_zipfile ` returns `False`

Comment: It means it's probably the old `.doc` format or not a `docx` file. did you change the file name from `doc` to `docx`? If yes then that will not work. Only `docx` file will work. For `.docx` file `is_zipfile` will return `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using python-docx by installing it with `pip install python-docx`.

Then, in you file, write something like this :

```
try:
  document = docx.Document('your_doc_name.docx')
except:
  document = docx.Document()
  document.save('your_doc_name.docx')
  print("Previous file was corrupted or didn't exist - new file was created.")
```